# how to make activity change orientation but stay in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I want one of my screens to be strictly landscape, however, when the device is turned around (upside down) but still in landscape mode, i want my activity to turn upside down as well

how do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

Answer (score 0):

Just set android:screenOrientation="landscape" in your activity tag in the manifest.  That will force it to landscape.

Comment: i did that, but this is not the desired result, i want my activity to always be in landscape, but i do want the screen to turn around, if the device itself is turned around

Answer (score 0):

In your activity/s you have to Override the ConfigurationChange and make it stay landscape.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wanted:

```
OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,Consts.SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DELAY_MS) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            Log.d(TAG,"sensor");
            if(orientation>Consts.THRESHOLD_FOR_ORIENTATION_CHANGE) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            }else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        }

    };
    if(orientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        orientationEventListener.enable();
    }
```